# Execute JQuery code in separate controller file

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Here is what i faced while developing AngularJS application.

My application consists of 2 parts. Each part contains 6 different partial views and I have 6 different controllers for each part. And of course one layout page to show them into it.

I want to call each controller in which partial view they belong to. But I failed. As far as i know, it happens because of custom `script` directive defined in AngularJS. But there must be a way/trick to achive that.

Briefly, I want to call inline JavaScript code lines or include external JavaScript file in partial view for AngularJS SPA. I searched on the internet but there is no simple and powerful way.

Answer (score 0):

Ithink what you need to do is to migrate your 'partial views' to directives. From there you'll be able to customize your 'Domain Definition Object'. The topic is quite broad but you can start here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Ex. in your DDO you have properties like templateURL/template, controller and scope so you can do whatever you want there and not be concerned with inline javascript etc.

Comment: while i was searching, i encountered almost same comment. but the problem is that, it should be done after the template rendered. also how can i call external js file with this way?

Comment: And by 'rendered' you mean after it has been interpolated?

Comment: for directives, `link` function is called after the template file (html) is rendered, isnt it?

Comment: Yes just after controller is finished executing

Comment: so how to interpolate or call external js file doing this? isnt there a way to do this in angularjs? should i use a different way?

Comment: Just create a service and inject it into your directive using DI.